# Code using tensorflow.mul() fails after upgrading to tensorflow v1.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

This code runs on Tensorflow v0.12.1, but fails on my new installation on TF v1.0. Is it that this function is deprecated? What's the function I should use? (Tensorflow up and running so I believe it's not a misconfiguration)

```
  File "***.py", line 115, in trainNetwork
    readout_action = tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(readout, a), reduction_indices = 1)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'mul'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `tf.mul()` function has been renamed to `tf.multiply()` in TensorFlow 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

For your kind information , `tf.mul`, `tf.sub` and `tf.neg` were used in the prior version of tensor-flow.  They have been deprecated.
You can instead use `tf.multiply`, `tf.subtract` and `tf.negative`. 
Thanks.